# Why is my text running down the screen instead of across in Python Terminal?

Tags: python, list, beautifulsoup

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 
'html.parser')
for tr in soup.findAll("table"):
    for td in tr.find_all("a"):
        table = str(td.text)
        print(table)

Code
International
Languages
England
en
enk
Welsh
wk
wkk
France
fr
fk
```

Why is this printing as follows, What I actually want to see the ouput below as a list:

```
['Code', 'International', 'Languages', 'England', 'en', 'enk', 'Welsh', 'wk', 'wkk', 'France', 'fr', 'fk']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
table = [] 
for tr in soup.findAll("table"):
    for td in tr.find_all("a"):
        table.append(str(td.text))
print table
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're printing item by item, and every `print` follows the data printed with a newline (unless expressly changed with `end` parameter). To get what you want use:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'html.parser')
print([str(td.text) for tr in soup.findAll("table") for td in tr.find_all("a")])
```